# How can I add child lists inside RecyclerView items efficiently, like in the Google Keep app?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a `RecyclerView` with a variety of modules in a grid, some of which contain lists of child items. How do I add those child lists without causing stuttering when the user scrolls?

I've tried adding a `LinearLayout` to my `ViewHolder`, and inflating the child views manually in `onBindViewHolder`, as well as using nested RecyclerViews. Both have performance issues, and nested RecyclerViews have the added problem of wrap_content not playing nice.

Any suggestions for optimizing performance? Am I missing a better way?

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return modules.get(position).getType().ordinal();
}

@Override
public ModuleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (types[viewType]) {
        case LINEARLAYOUTSTATBLOCK:
            return new ModuleLLBlockViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.module_block, parent, false));
        case RECYCLERVIEWSTATBLOCK:
            return new ModuleRVBlockViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.module_block, parent, false));
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ModuleViewHolder vh, final int position) {
    switch (types[vh.getItemViewType()]) {
        case LINEARLAYOUTSTATBLOCK:
            bind((ModuleLLBlockViewHolder) vh, (StatBlockModule) modules.get(position));
            break;
        case RECYCLERVIEWSTATBLOCK:
            bind((ModuleRVBlockViewHolder) vh, (StatBlockModule) modules.get(position));
            break;
    }
}

private void bind(ModuleLLBlockViewHolder vh, TitleTextBlockModule module) {
    for (int i = 0; i < module.getStats().size(); i++) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(vh.linearLayout.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, vh.linearLayout, true);
        v.setId(i);
        TextView tvCategory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
        CustomView customView = (CustomView) v.findViewById(R.id.customView);
        tvCategory.setText(stat.getCategory());
        customView.setRating(stat.getRating());
    }
}

private void bind(ModuleRVBlockViewHolder vh, StatBlockModule module) {
    vh.childRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(vh.itemView.getContext()));
    vh.childRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ChildAdapter(module.getStats()));
}
```

[image: Google Keep example]

Comment: Good question.  I am currently trying to do the same.  If I figure it out, I will post an answer.

Comment: Any update on this question? I've successfully implemented a child RecyclerView inside its parent's item and it works but with poor performance..
even tried this to make it perform better: https://medium.com/@p.tournaris/recyclerview-how-we-achieved-60-fps-tips-in-workables-android-app-recyclerviews-c646c796473c#.6elg95wbi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Android Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html), RecyclerView now obeys wrap_content, so it can be used inside a list item.

You should set `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` on the inner RecyclerView(s) so scrolling is handled by the outer RecyclerView alone.